# I how setup a slice inline function in redux toolkit

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit

I have this function in

```
    export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    credentials: {},
    isLoading: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    isLoading: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = !state.isLoading;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(signInByEmail.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.credentials = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(signInByEmail.rejected, (state, action) => {
        Alert.alert(
          "OOPS!",
          "Wrong Email or Password",
          [{ text: "Try Again" }],
          { cancelable: false }
        );
      })
      .addCase(signUpByEmail.pending, state => state.isLoading = true)
      .addCase(signUpByEmail.fulfilled, (state, action)=> {

      })
  },
});
```

its Giving me an error in state.isLoading = true

But if i do it like this

```
    export const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "auth",
  initialState: {
    credentials: {},
    isLoading: false,
  },
  reducers: {
    isLoading: (state) => {
      state.isLoading = !state.isLoading;
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addCase(signInByEmail.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.credentials = action.payload;
      })
      .addCase(signInByEmail.rejected, (state, action) => {
        Alert.alert(
          "OOPS!",
          "Wrong Email or Password",
          [{ text: "Try Again" }],
          { cancelable: false }
        );
      })
      .addCase(signUpByEmail.pending, (state, action) => {
          state.isLoading = true
      })
      .addCase(signUpByEmail.fulfilled, (state, action)=> {

      })
  },
});
```

After i broke into another line i get no error. What an I missing.

This is the error im getting just in case.

No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(actionCreator: AsyncThunkPendingActionCreator<{ email: string; password: string; }>, reducer: CaseReducer<{ credentials: {}; isLoading: boolean; }, PayloadAction<undefined, string, { ...; }, never>>): ActionReducerMapBuilder<...>', gave the following error.
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'void | { credentials: {}; isLoading: boolean; }'.
Overload 2 of 2, '(type: string, reducer: CaseReducer<{ credentials: {}; isLoading: boolean; }, Action>):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error has to do with what is being **returned** from your reducer.  In the case that works, you aren't returning anything.  It is a `void` function which mutates the draft state.

```
.addCase(signUpByEmail.pending, (state, action) => {
     state.isLoading = true
})
```

There is an alternative syntax which is also acceptable where you return a new state as a replacement for the current state, ie.

```
.addCase(signUpByEmail.pending, (state, action) => ({...state, isLoading: true}))
```

But the state that you return must be a complete state object.

```
Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'void | { credentials: {}; isLoading: boolean; }'
```

The error says that the two valid return types are `void` as in the first example or the complete state `{ credentials: {}; isLoading: boolean; }` as in the second.

The error also says that you are returning `boolean`.  This is because arrow functions without braces always return something.

This function `a` mutates the object and returns `void` / `undefined`:

```
const a = (num: {n: number}): void => { num.n = 1; }
```

But when we don't have the curly braces `{}`, we return the result of the expression.  We both mutate the object **and return `1`**.

```
const b = (num: {n: number}): number => num.n = 1;
```

[Try it out!](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDAFGArgWwFwwN5i4aYBGApgE4C%20AlLgG4gCWAJkgHz4zEB0YSMAIwBuGFQCwAKCmhIsEgLRZcBIlnLU63dZQ7bMfASKlSANmViYAngHkSAKwGqYAVgmTZEEOZ6mQAcxQ4FGs7exoaYRlwLx8-QNCHSJNJRMdkZzdoyG8yXwCUEhDbJOSPGNz8hJLwqMkgA)

In short, the braces are necessary to prevent you from returning a value when assigning `state.isLoading = true`.  Without them, you return `true` which is not a valid return type for a reducer.